# Azure ADF using Azure Batch throws Shared Access Signature generation error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-batch, azure-adf

I am working on a simple Azure Data Factory pipeline where I have simply added a Batch Service and in that specified the Batch Service account (which I have created thru linked service and tested the connection is working). In the command I am just running a simple "ls" command and when I do a debug run I get this error:  "Cannot create Shared Access Signature unless Account Key credentials are used." I have following linked services "Azure Batch", "Azure Blob Storage" and Key Vault (where we store the access key). All linked services connections are working properly.

Any help on how to fix this error: "Cannot create Shared Access Signature unless Account Key credentials are used."

Azure Batch Linked service:
[image]

Azure Storage Linked service:
[image]

Azure Data factory pipeline:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because you use "Managed Identity" to connect ADF to the Storage. It will say "successful" when doing a connection test on the linked services but when this storage is used for a Batch, it needs to have "Account Key" authentication type (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide#error-code-2505)).